# Pentaho Data Integration Unable To Open in Repository

Tags: pentaho, etl, business-intelligence, pdi

Pentaho Data Integration is giving me an error every time I try to run it on the server.

It says that it cannot find my transformation in the repository, but I know it's there. I triple checked.

Why do you think I am getting this error message? What could be the cause?

Comment: Can it find other jobs/transformations? Have you checked repositories.xml on the server to see if it points to the repo you expect?

Comment: are you using carte server ?